# Stream sorting issue

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of items (MyDetail object) that I want to sort with stream sorting methods. The object has 3 fields: field1, field2, field3.
I want to sort by field3 first then field2 then field1, all with reversed order.
So I wrote a method sortMyList.

I have a list of unsorted items unSortedDetails as the following:
                    myDetail1: "20180201", false, false
                    myDetail2: "20180101", false, false
                    myDetail3: "20180101", false, true

after sortMyList(unSortedDetails), I expect my result would be              myDetail3, myDetail1, myDetail2, but the actual result is myDetail1, myDetail3, myDetail2,  Why?

so if I implement Comparable for MyDetail like the following, then it works as expected. this is so strange.  I could not figure out why. thanks for any help!

```
public List<MyDetail> sortMyList(List<MyDetail> unSortedDetails){
    List<MyDetail> myDetails = unSortedDetails
                        .stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyDetail::getField11).reversed()
                                .thenComparing(MyDetail::getField2).reversed()
                                .thenComparing(MyDetail::getField3).reversed())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return myDetails;
                        }

                        @Setter
                        @Getter
                        public class MyDetail{
                            String field1;
                            Boolean field2; 
                            Boolean field3; 
                        }



                @Setter
                @Getter
                public class MyDetail implement Comparable<MyDetail>{
                    String field1;
                    Boolean field2; 
                    Boolean field3; 

                        @Override
                        public int compareTo(MyDetail o) {
                            if (this == o || this.equals(o)) return 0;
                            if (field3) return -1;
                            if (o.field3) return 1;
                            if (!field3 && !o.field3 && field2) return -1;
                            if(!field3 && !o.field3 &&!field2 && o.field2) return 1;
                            if(!field3 && !o.field3
                                    &&!field2 && !o.field2){
                                return o.field1.compareTo(field1);
                            }
                            return 0;
}
                }
```

Comment: Your `field*` fields are of the type `String`, but you're trying to treat them as `boolean` conditions in your if-statements.

Comment: oh, Sorry, field3, field2 are boolean, field1 is string, updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few problems with your Comparator. First is that each time you call `reversed()` you are reversing *all* previous settings of comparator.

So your comparator represents (see steps in comments, `FieldX` reduced to `Fx`)

```
Comparator.comparing(MyDetail::getField11)     //  F1 ASC
          .reversed()                          //~(F1 ASC) 
                                               //  F1 DESC 
          .thenComparing(MyDetail::getField2)  //  F1 DESC, F2 ASC  
          .reversed()                          //~(F1 DESC, F2 ASC) 
                                               //  F1 ASC,  F2 DESC
          .thenComparing(MyDetail::getField3)  //  F1 ASC,  F2 DESC, F3 ASC
          .reversed()                          //~(F1 ASC,  F2 DESC, F3 ASC)
                                               //  F1 DESC, F2 ASC,  F3 DESC
```

so you end up with order `Field1 DESC, Field2 ASC,  Field3 DESC`.

To specify reversed order for each field do it by ***passing already reversed comparator of that field*** like `.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(YourClass::getField).reversed())`.

---

Next issue is order of fields used by Comparator. In your question you said:

> I want to sort by field3 first then field2 then field1

but your comparator first checks field1, then field2, then field3 (since in that order you added them via `.thenComparing`).

Your code should be more like

```
Comparator.comparing(MyDetail::getField13).reversed()
          .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(MyDetail::getField2).reversed())
          .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(MyDetail::getField1).reversed())
```

So you are creating `~(F3 ASC), ~(F2 ASC), ~(F1 ASC)` which results in `F3 DESC, F2 DESC, F1 DESC`.

---

BTW as [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658844/stream-sorting-issue/54659126?noredirect=1#comment96129207_54659126) by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) you can achieve same effect by

```
Comparator.comparing(MyDetail::getField3)
          .thenComparing(MyDetail::getField2) 
          .thenComparing(MyDetail::getField1)
          .reversed()
```

Notice that `Comparaor.comparing(FunctionToValue)` and `thenComparing(FunctionToValue)` will create **ASCending** Comparators for selected Value.

So first 3 lines construct Comparator describing order `F3 ASC, F2 ASC, F1 ASC`. After reversing it
`~(F3 ASC, F2 ASC, F1 ASC)` also gives us desired `F3 DESC, F2 DESC, F1 DESC`.

Comment: thanks a lot!  Your explanation is very clear. Love it!

Comment: One more question, so stream sort vs. comparable on class, which way is faster? I would vote the later but I tested and did not see much difference between the two.

Comment: I can't help you now but that sounds like an interesting question. Consider creating separate post for it and include your test. Anyway I probably wouldn't be bothered at first by performance since purpose of `Comparable` interface is to provide *default* order for elements, while purpose of `Comparator` is to let others use any *custom made* order. We usually don't need to think about performance of default order vs user-defined one, but like I said this may be interesting question for others to answer.

Comment: You’re overcomplicating things. To get a comparator using reverse order for all properties, just create a comparator for all properties and reverse the end result: `Comparator.comparing(MyDetail::getField3) .thenComparing(MyDetail::getField2) .thenComparing(MyDetail::getField1).reversed()`

Comment: @Holger True, I focused mainly on explaining problems (misuse of `reversed` and wrong order of fields). But tbh while approach suggested by you is valid, IMO using `thenComparing(reversedComparator)` is easier to follow, so also less error-prone. Anyway thanks for pointing it out, will add your variant to the answer.

Comment: @Holger, thanks! Yes agree. your approach is easier to understand.